# Open port only on OpenVPN network with iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I'm running an OpenVPN network and one of the VPN clients in my network is a web server which provides access to some internal services used by my application.

Normally, on a public facing web server I would open port 80 with iptables like this:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

However, doing this for my internal web server, this will expose port 80 on the private IP (`192.168.x.x`) which is what I do not want since it would potentially allow other VM's on the same network (which aren't necessarily controlled by me) access to this machine.

How do I set the iptables rule in such a way that port 80 is only accessible through the VPN IP (`10.8.x.x`) so that only VPN client in my network can access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.8.0.0/16 -d 192.168.X.X --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Should do the trick... unless you are nat-ing first.

You could even add a `-i tun0` or something, to limit on the interface name.

Comment: I've used the `-i tun0`, which seems to work great!